Is there a way to run a suite of Julia tests from the command line, rather than from the REPL?
Is there a way to run the tests from the command line, rather than having to go through the slightly awkward process of running the following commands in the REPL?
$ julia --package
julia> import Pkg
julia> Pkg.test()


Maybe you're looking for % julia -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.test("package")'?

@AndreWildberg there isn't a better way than this? eg in Rust you have cargo test, for Python something like python3 -m pytest can be made to work

You can also cd to  the test direcrory (or use the project flag) and run "julia runtests.jl"

I usually do
$ cd <where Project.toml lives>
$ julia --project=. test/runtests.jl

